# VB / ASP page does not add first item to list in click method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have written a basic shopping page. When a user clicks an item and valid quantity, they add the item to the cart with the add item button. This should grab the session variable which holds the list, add the new item, and then put the updated list back into the session.

EDIT: 
It seems the items ARE being added but not shown until the next page reload. Why?

For the most part it works, except the initial click, for which the count of items remains 0 unless I click add again. From there everything works fine.

I am sure I am overlooking something simple.

In the pages Load Method, I create the new list if no session exists., otherwise using the existing list:

```
If IsNothing(Session("CustomerItems")) Then
    CustomerItemsList = New List(Of CustomerProduct)
    'Session("CustomerItems") = CustomerItemsList
    Response.Write("Session did not exist yet.")
Else
    CustomerItemsList = Session("CustomerItems")
    Response.Write("Session Loaded.")
End If
```

Next the values are added to a list box control from an array to show the items.

Finally I placed these lines. I will use the .IsPostBack page to list all items in the list later on:

```
If Page.IsPostBack Then
        Response.Write("<br>Page has been posted back. There Are Currently " & CustomerItemsList.Count & " items.")
Else
        Response.Write("<br>Page has NOT been posted back. There Are Currently " & CustomerItemsList.Count & " items.")
End If
```

And finally, my click event looks like this:

```
    Protected Sub btnAddItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddItem.Click
    CustomerItemsList = Session("CustomerItems")

    Dim CustomerItem As CustomerProduct
    CustomerItem.Description = ProductArray(lstItemDescriptions.SelectedIndex, 0)
    CustomerItem.ItemQty = txtItemQty.Text
    CustomerItem.BulkFee = ProductArray(lstItemDescriptions.SelectedIndex, 1)
    CustomerItem.UnitWeight = ProductArray(lstItemDescriptions.SelectedIndex, 2)
    CustomerItem.TotalWeight = Double.Parse(ProductArray(lstItemDescriptions.SelectedIndex, 2)) * Double.Parse(txtItemQty.Text)
    CustomerItem.UnitCost = ProductArray(lstItemDescriptions.SelectedIndex, 3)
    CustomerItem.TotalCost = CustomerItem.UnitCost * CustomerItem.ItemQty

    CustomerItemsList.Add(CustomerItem)

    Session("CustomerItems") = CustomerItemsList

End Sub
```

Now, I've gone over this thing a few times, and its probably simple, but it just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Is this Classic ASP with VBScript or asp.net with VB.net.  It looks like the latter, it can't be both

Comment: this project is vb.net.

Comment: Are you reloading the page on clicking `add` button? I believe you would need to refresh the cart control to reflect the changes. Also, can you explain what exactly is you main question now?

Comment: `Dim CustomerItem As CustomerProduct` should probably be `Dim CustomerItem As New CustomerProduct` otherwise you will get an obj instance error